# How to automatically modify (fill down) separate IMPORTRANGE formulas for each consecutive individual cell in a column, instead of the entire range

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Is it possible to automatically modify (or fill down) separate IMPORTRANGE formulas for each consecutive individual cell in a column, instead of the entire range?

Example of three consecutive formulas in three consecutive cells:

1. B4
   `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGXMw1zKXbfjyZp81S8ICHtiUJZhQe1VQhntAoPOPIw/edit#gid=564463244", "DATABASE: Schools [DO NOT RENAME]!B4")`
2. B5
   `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGXMw1zKXbfjyZp81S8ICHtiUJZhQe1VQhntAoPOPIw/edit#gid=564463244", "DATABASE: Schools [DO NOT RENAME]!B5")`
3. B6
   `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGXMw1zKXbfjyZp81S8ICHtiUJZhQe1VQhntAoPOPIw/edit#gid=564463244", "DATABASE: Schools [DO NOT RENAME]!B6")`

Separate formulas for each individual cell makes it possible to sort data in the destination spreadsheets while remaining connected to the other columns in those spreadsheets.

I discovered this after realizing that one formula for the range of cells will not allow for column sorting in relation to other cells in the sheet.

Example of one formula for the range of 3 cells:
`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGXMw1zKXbfjyZp81S8ICHtiUJZhQe1VQhntAoPOPIw/edit#gid=564463244", "DATABASE: Schools [DO NOT RENAME]!B4:B6")`

I was very disappointed to learn that basic A-Z sorting is not possible with the `ImportRange` data in destination spreadsheets. I’m so glad that it’s possible to sort after importing each cell but I’m not happy about modifying each formula manually (filling the formula down and changing the number after B in each cell for the entire column, as in the three formulas above).

Is it possible to create a formula for this? To add a `+1` to each formula in the consecutive cells?

Comment: Try using SORT() formula.  =SORT(IMPORTRANGE(1RGXMw1zKXbfjyZp81S8ICHtiUJZhQe1VQhntAoPOPIw", "DATABASE: Schools [DO NOT RENAME]!B4:B6"),1,TRUE), where TRUE is for ascending and FALSE for descending order.

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using separate IMPORTRANGE calls in each row. Google Sheets has limits on the number of IMPORTRANGE formulas that can be used in each sheet. Last I checked, that was 40—which will quickly be used up. I second the suggestion by Oleg_S.